# checkbox value not shown on html page

Tags: html, checkbox, twig

I am working on a checkbox that is used to give the use access to a referral link for his page. However the value of the checkbox isn't shown it remains blank even though the value of the checkbox is true

when I log the value of the referralLink it returns true yet here it remains blank

```
<input type='checkbox'  name='referral' id="referral" 
value="{{category.referralLink}}"/><label for="referral">Referral</label>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw a comment mentioning using checked="checked" but it got removed. I managed to fix it with that though just slightly altered it. Maybe not the most elegant fix but it is working. So to the guy (can't remember name)  thanks!

```
<input type='checkbox'  name='referral' id="referral" {% if category.referralLink %} checked="checked"{% endif %}/><label for="referral">Referral</label>
```

Comment: What do you mean not the most elegant way? This is the only correct way to check a checkbox. The value does not mean anything with a checkbox. Just give it a name and in the controller you test for isset($_POST['chk_name']) to test if an user checked a box